# How can I get not this error: 'tuple' object does not support item assignmen?

Tags: python, arrays, tuples

```
telefoon=("Sandra","06-1000000","Robin","06-111111","Tom","06-333333");

telefoon["Tom"]="06-333333";
telefoon["Sandra"]="06-1000000";
telefoon["Robin"]="06-111111";

naam=input("Van wie wil je het telefoonnummer weten?");
print(telefoon[naam]);
```

Comment: `tuples` are immutalbe. if you want to be able to assign and change items you need a `list`. (i.e `telefoon=["Sandra", ...]`). what you seem to need here is a `dict` though : `telefoon={"Sandra":"06-1000000", ...}`.

Answer (score 2):

> The error is because you are trying to assign values in a Tuple which
>   is not possible as Tuples in Python are immutable.

Do this:

```
telefoon={"Sandra":"06-1000000","Robin":"06-111111","Tom":"06-333333"}

telefoon["Tom"]="06-333333"
telefoon["Sandra"]="06-1000000"
telefoon["Robin"]="06-111111"

telefoon["naam"] = input("Van wie wil je het telefoonnummer weten?")
print(telefoon["naam"])
```

Also, semicolons are not necessary in Python.

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

In Python you have some collection datatypes you should know about: Tuples, Lists and Dictionaries. The difference in the syntax is their parentheses:

```
my_tuple = (0, 1, 2)
my_list = [0, 1, 2]
my_dictionary = {'zero': 0, 'one': 1, 'two': 2}
```

**Tuples** are immutable, which means you can't change it's value. This is why you get the error.
**Lists** are very similar but are mutable.
What you want is a **dictionary** because you want to assign a value to a key-string:

```py
telefoon = {'Sandra': '06-1000000',
            'Robin': '06-111111',
            'Tom': '06-333333'}

naam = input("Van wie wil je het telefoonnummer weten?")
print(telefoon[naam])
```

And by the way: this is python - you don't need semicolons ;)

Answer (score 0):

Turn `telefoon` into a dictionary:

```
telefoon={"Sandra":"06-1000000","Robin":"06-111111","Tom":"06-333333"};
```